# Find path of object property, recursively

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, recursion, path-finding

I want to print path of object key, dynamically. Here is my code:

```
   const Tree = ({ data }) => {
     let path = "onboarding";
  
      return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
        if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
          path = path + "." + key;
          return (
              <Tree data={data[key]}></Tree> 
          );
        }

        if (typeof data[key] === "object") {
          path = path + "." + key;
          return (
              <Tree data={data[key]}></Tree>
          );
        } else {
          path = path + "." + key;    
          return (
            <input defaultValue={data[key]}
              style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
              disabled={!this.props.isEditable}/>

          );
        }
      });
    };
```

and its my data

```
  onboarding: {
    enumType: 1,
    key: "key1",
    steps: [
      {
        title: "STEP ONE",
        description: "des1",
        instructions: [
          {
            icon: "step_power",
            label: {
              text: "text1",
              color: "A11111",
              location: "top",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "STEP TWO",
        description: "des2",
        instructions: [
          {
            icon: "step_power",
            label: {
              text: "text2",
              color: "A11111",
              location: "top",
            },
          },
       ],
    }
```

And i want to print path of key for each iteration, expected output :

- "enumType"
- "key"
- "steps"
- "steps[0]"
- "steps[0].title"
- . . .
- "steps[1].instructions[0].label.location"

Comment: Is `onboarding` a property of another object? The syntax you used seems to start in the middle of an object literal.

Comment: No actually, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the path along as prop, I made a codebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-browser-crgd9r

Edit: adding relevant code here as comment suggested

```
const Tree = ({ path, data }) => {
  // We have 3 cases: Array, Object or neither
  // If we have an array we want to cycle through the elements
  // and keep track of the index
  // If we have an object we want to cicle through the keys
  // otherwise just return the value

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.map((element, index) => {
      let currentPath = `${path}[${index}]`;
      return (
        <Tree
          path={currentPath}
          data={element}
          key={currentPath}
        ></Tree>
      );
    });
  } else if (data instanceof Object) {
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
      let currentPath = path !== "" ? `${path}.${key}` : key;
      return <Tree data={data[key]} path={currentPath} key={currentPath} />;
    });
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{path}</label>
        <input defaultValue={data} style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [answering questions well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering).  Please post relevant code inside the answer itself.  External links are fine to give additional context and such, but the answer should stand alone without that external resource.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to separate out the path-extraction code from the DOM-generation part.  This would let you work with more reusable functions.

Here is how I might write the path-extraction piece, in two different ways.  First as an all-in one function for your output format:

```js
const stringPaths = (o, p = '') =>
  Array .isArray (o) 
    ? o .flatMap ((v, i) => [p, ...stringPaths (v, `${p}[${i}]`)]) .filter (Boolean)
  : Object (o) === o
    ? [
        p, 
        ... Object .entries (o) .flatMap (([k, v]) => stringPaths (v, p ? `${p}.${k}` : k))
      ] .filter (Boolean)
  : p


const onboarding = {enumType: 1, key: "key1", steps: [{title: "STEP ONE", description: "des1", instructions: [{icon: "step_power", label: {text: "text1", color: "A11111", location: "top"}}]}, {title: "STEP TWO", description: "des2", instructions: [{icon: "step_power", label: {text: "text2", color: "A11111", location: "top"}}]}]}
 
console .log (stringPaths (onboarding))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

And then second, in my preferred style, generating a more widely useful intermediate format (`[["enumType"], ["key"], ["steps"], ["steps", 0], ["steps", 0, "title"], ..., ["steps", 1, "instructions", 0, "label", "location"]]`, and then converting that into your target format:

```js
const getPaths = (o) => Object (o) === o
  ? Object .entries (o) 
      .flatMap (([k, v], _, __, k1 = Array .isArray (o) ? Number (k) : k) => 
        [[k1], ...getPaths (v) .map (p => [k1, ...p])]
      )
  : []

const stringPaths = (o) => 
  getPaths (o) .map (
    (path) => path .reduce ((p, n, i) => i == 0 ? n : Number .isInteger (n) ? `${p}[${n}]` : `${p}.${n}`, ``)
  )

const onboarding = {enumType: 1, key: "key1", steps: [{title: "STEP ONE", description: "des1", instructions: [{icon: "step_power", label: {text: "text1", color: "A11111", location: "top"}}]}, {title: "STEP TWO", description: "des2", instructions: [{icon: "step_power", label: {text: "text2", color: "A11111", location: "top"}}]}]}
 
console .log (stringPaths (onboarding))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I think this breakdown make for much nicer coding.